# Reinstalling X11 drivers Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, xorg, xorg.conf

After a recent upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 xserver would no longer start on my workstation. When running

```
startx
```

the following error occurs:

```
(EE) module ABI major version (6) doesn't match the server's version (8)
xinit: connection to X server lost
waiting for X server to shut down (EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

I'm suspecting that the X11 drivers have not been rebuilt. I am at a loss, however, as I am not familiar with these steps. I've checked the xorg logs; their contents are:

**Xorg.0.log**

```
[     8.467] 
X.Org X Server 1.15.1
Release Date: 2014-04-13
[     8.467] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[     8.467] Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-37-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[     8.467] Current Operating System: Linux senectus 3.13.0-34-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 13 15:45:27 UTC 2014 x86_64
[     8.467] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-34-generic root=UUID=f44b71b3-2138-4161-9514-4f80bfc53269 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[     8.467] Build Date: 16 April 2014  01:36:29PM
[     8.467] xorg-server 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[     8.467] Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
[     8.467]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[     8.467] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[     8.467] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue Sep  2 19:13:36 2014
[     8.469] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[     8.470] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[     8.470] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[     8.470] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[     8.470] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[     8.470] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[     8.470] (==) Automatically adding devices
[     8.470] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[     8.470] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[     8.470] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[     8.470]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     8.470] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[     8.470]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     8.470] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[     8.470]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     8.470] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[     8.470]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     8.470] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[     8.470]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     8.470] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[     8.470] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[     8.470] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[     8.470] (II) Loader magic: 0x7fc4c1402d60
[     8.470] (II) Module ABI versions:
[     8.470]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[     8.470]    X.Org Video Driver: 15.0
[     8.470]    X.Org XInput driver : 20.0
[     8.470]    X.Org Server Extension : 8.0
[     8.471] (--) PCI:*(0:1:0:0) 10de:1213:1043:2119 rev 161, Mem @ 0xf6000000/16777216, 0xf0000000/67108864, 0xf4000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000e000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[     8.472] Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[     8.472] Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[     8.472] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[     8.472] Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[     8.472] Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[     8.472] Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[     8.472] Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[     8.472] Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[     8.472] Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[     8.472] Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[     8.472] Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[     8.472] Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[     8.472] Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[     8.472] Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[     8.472] Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[     8.472] Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[     8.472] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[     8.472] Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[     8.472] Initializing built-in extension RECORD
[     8.472] Initializing built-in extension DPMS
[     8.472] Initializing built-in extension Present
[     8.472] Initializing built-in extension DRI3
[     8.472] Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
[     8.472] Initializing built-in extension XVideo
[     8.472] Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[     8.472] Initializing built-in extension SELinux
[     8.472] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[     8.472] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
[     8.472] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
[     8.472] Initializing built-in extension DRI2
[     8.472] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[     8.487] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[     8.496] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     8.496]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[     8.496]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[     8.496] (EE) module ABI major version (6) doesn't match the server's version (8)
[     8.496] (II) UnloadModule: "glx"
[     8.496] (II) Unloading glx
[     8.496] (EE) Failed to load module "glx" (module requirement mismatch, 0)
[     8.496] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[     8.496] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 1
[     8.496] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
[     8.496] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[     8.496] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 4
[     8.496] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[     8.496] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[     8.497] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[     8.497] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[     8.497] (II) Unloading nvidia
[     8.497] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
[     8.497] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[     8.497] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[     8.501] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     8.501]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 1.0.10
[     8.501]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     8.501]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[     8.501] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[     8.501] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[     8.501] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     8.501]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.8.1
[     8.501]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     8.501]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[     8.501] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[     8.502] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[     8.502] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     8.502]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.4.4
[     8.502]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     8.502]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[     8.502] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[     8.502] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[     8.502] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     8.502]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 2.3.3
[     8.502]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     8.502]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[     8.502] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[     8.502] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 1
[     8.502] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
[     8.502] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[     8.502] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 4
[     8.502] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[     8.502] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[     8.502] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[     8.502] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[     8.502] (II) Unloading nvidia
[     8.502] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
[     8.502] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[     8.502] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[     8.502] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     8.502]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 1.0.10
[     8.502]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     8.502]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[     8.502] (II) UnloadModule: "nouveau"
[     8.502] (II) Unloading nouveau
[     8.502] (II) Failed to load module "nouveau" (already loaded, 0)
[     8.502] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[     8.503] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[     8.503] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     8.503]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.8.1
[     8.503]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     8.503]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[     8.503] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[     8.503] (II) Unloading modesetting
[     8.503] (II) Failed to load module "modesetting" (already loaded, 0)
[     8.503] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[     8.503] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[     8.503] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     8.503]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.4.4
[     8.503]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     8.503]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[     8.503] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[     8.503] (II) Unloading fbdev
[     8.503] (II) Failed to load module "fbdev" (already loaded, 0)
[     8.503] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[     8.503] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[     8.503] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     8.503]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 2.3.3
[     8.503]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     8.503]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[     8.503] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[     8.503] (II) Unloading vesa
[     8.503] (II) Failed to load module "vesa" (already loaded, 0)
[     8.503] (II) NOUVEAU driver Date:   Thu Nov 7 14:56:48 2013 +1000
[     8.503] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[     8.503]    RIVA TNT        (NV04)
[     8.503]    RIVA TNT2       (NV05)
[     8.503]    GeForce 256     (NV10)
[     8.503]    GeForce 2       (NV11, NV15)
[     8.503]    GeForce 4MX     (NV17, NV18)
[     8.503]    GeForce 3       (NV20)
[     8.503]    GeForce 4Ti     (NV25, NV28)
[     8.503]    GeForce FX      (NV3x)
[     8.503]    GeForce 6       (NV4x)
[     8.503]    GeForce 7       (G7x)
[     8.503]    GeForce 8       (G8x)
[     8.503]    GeForce GTX 200 (NVA0)
[     8.503]    GeForce GTX 400 (NVC0)
[     8.503] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[     8.503] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[     8.503] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[     8.503] (++) using VT number 7

[     8.517] (EE) [drm] KMS not enabled
[     8.517] (EE) [drm] KMS not enabled
[     8.518] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[     8.518] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[     8.518] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[     8.518] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[     8.518] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[     8.518] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[     8.518] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[     8.518] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[     8.518] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     8.518]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 0.0.2
```

Reinstalling the Nvidia drivers does not fix this issue. How may I rebuild the X11 drivers?

Comment: try, sudo service lightdm start

Comment: Sadly, the error persists.

Comment: try to purge the ubuntu-desktop, and reinstall it:

sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop

sudo apt-get auto-clean

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: Happened to me before, forced me to make a fresh install, im sorry.